# Getting error: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSRectFill', but __NSRectFill works, why?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to Swift 4, coding in Xcode 9.  Trying to create a very simple MacOS drawing app just to learn a bit more about Swift.  I copied some very simple tutorial code, but are getting an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSRectFill'. I noticed that the compiler hinted that I use __NSRectFill and this worked...but why?  Am I doing some wrong?

```
import Cocoa

class GraphView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        NSColor.white.setFill()
        NSRectFill(bounds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Starting in Swift 3, `NSRectFill` has been made a method of `NSRect / CGRect`. So you should have called `bounds.fill()` instead.

Deep down though, it may still relies on some Core Foundation routines like `__NSRectFill`. It's better that you avoid those double-underscored functions since they are low-level system stuffs that are poorly documented (at least publicly).